# Backbone + calling function from inside render() is throw uncaught reference error

Tags: backbone.js, render

I am new to backbone.js. I am trying to call a function which loads the template with data coming from webapi.

var BrowseNavListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#tocDrawerNav"),

```
initialize: function () {
    debugger;
    $("#hfReferenceId").val($("#hfChannelId").val());
    _.bindAll(this, 'rendersCollectively', 'RenderFocusAreaBladeContent');
    this.render();
},
render: function () {
    debugger;
    var that = this;
    var navigator = new Navigators();
    navigator.fetch({
        success: function (navigatorList) {
            debugger;
            if (navigatorList.length > 0) {
                **RenderFocusAreaBladeContent(navigatorList);**
            }
        },
        error: function (x) {
            debugger;
            alert(x);
        }
    })
},

RenderFocusAreaBladeContent: function (navigatorList) {
    debugger;
    divIterator = divIterator.split('_')[divIterator.split('_').length - 2] + "_"
        + (parseInt(divIterator.split('_')[divIterator.split('_').length - 1]) + parseInt(1)).toString();

    var template = '<div class="tocColumn " id="' + divIterator + '"><label>US Channel</label>';
    var navigatorListmodel = navigatorList.toJSON();
    var content = Loadtemplates("browsetemplate");
    var browsetemplate = Handlebars.compile(content);
    template += browsetemplate({ navigatorList: navigatorListmodel });
    $("#tocDrawerNav").append(template);
    $('.view').unbind('click');

    $('.view').click(function (n) {

        divIteratorBlade = "divIteratorBlade_1";
        $("#tocColumns").empty();
        $("#hfReferenceId").val("SUB" + n.currentTarget.id);

        var browseNested = new BrowseListViewBlade();
        browseNested.render(n);
    });
}
```

});

I am getting uncaught reference error while calling RenderFocusAreaBladeContent() inside render

Answer (score 5):

shouldn't it be

```
that.RenderFocusAreaBladeContent(navigatorList);
```

?